# Child theme necessary on purchased template?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I am new to developing on Joomla and I am wondering if you feel it is necessary to use child themes when modifying a 3rd party template? I bought a template that I want to start modifying but am wondering if it's best to create a child theme first or is that only for if I am modifying the default templates provided by Joomla i.e. protostar?

Is there anything to worry about if I do not use a child theme?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it is totally fine to modify a non-core template in Joomla because generally Joomla templates are never upgraded.  However some Joomla templates contain lots of advanced functionality, especially ones that are designed to work with specific components, and will indeed require updating.  If you think you may update the theme in the future then you will need to duplicate the theme and modify the theme name in several spots as detailed here:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Modifying_a_Joomla!_Template

Comment: Duplicating and renaming the theme will not serve any benefit for future updates. The unmodified template will get the update and the duplicated one will not. And even if the duplicated one could get the updates, your modified code would still be at risk for getting erased.

Answer (score 1):

In general practice, you should ALWAYS use child templates. You never know what bugs, security issues, or upgrade compatibilities may be revealed in the future. If you have customized the 3rd party template, then you will have the sole responsibility of applying future updates to your customized template as your support from the developer will likely be voided. And, updating the template directly could erase all of your customizations and render the site less than desired or even unusable. *Unfortunately, Joomla!'s templating system does not work quite the same as WordPress's theming system, so the process is not exactly the same and your capabilities are limited.*

However, that said most 3rd party templates provide a "customization framework" that allows you to add your own code and styles without modifying the template's files. You would need to evaluate your template's customization capabilities and the extent to which your want to customize the template to decide if this is a safe route for your website.

If you are using the 3rd party template as a framework to develop your own custom template, then it should be fine to modify the template directly. However, you would want to [change many of the settings in the template](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Modifying_a_Joomla!_Template) (as mentioned in [@jamesgarrett's answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18952/5638)) so the Joomla! Update utility does not check the template's "update site" for future updates.

---

Learn more: [Creating child templates](https://www.lynda.com/Joomla-tutorials/Creating-child-templates/174920/370312-4.html), [How to update to the latest version of a Joomla! template](https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/tutorials/template-update-guide)